# Wordpress pagination returning empty page

Tags: wordpress, pagination

My blog page displays the posts fine, but the pagination is becoming quite troublesome.

The pagination displays 'older posts' on the first page (blog landing page) but when I click 'older posts' it takes me to /blog/page/2/ but empty.

Below is PHP I'm using.

```
 <?php get_header(); ?>
<?php
  if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
  get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
  endwhile;?>
  <?php next_posts_link( 'Older posts' ); ?>
  <?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: So, presumably there aren't any older posts? The example in [the documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link) shows how to test to see if there are any before outputting the link (under "Check if next link exists".)

Comment: There's only the one link that appears.

<a href="http://localhost:8888/blog/page/2/">Older posts</a>

I have 4 test posts in total and in the settings it is set to display 2 per page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer.

I did not have a page created for 'Blog', so nor was it set up as the 'posts page' in the reading settings.

I've created the page and it is all working as it should.